Show that the class of all semigroups forms a category, where morphisms are defined as semigroup homomorphisms.
In Peter Szekeres's A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics, the exercise on page 24 asks

Show that the class of all semigroups, Example 1.12, forms a category, where morphisms are defined as semigroup homomorphisms.

Example 1.12 simply defines a semigroup as a set $S$ with an associative law of composition defined on it. The definition of a category on the previous page states (among other things):

For each pair of objects $A, B$ of $\mathcal{O}$ there is a set $\mathrm{Mor}(A,B)$ whose elements are called morphisms from $A$ to $B$, usually denoted $A \xrightarrow{\phi} B$.

Note that $\mathcal{O}$ is the class.
Combining the above question about semigroups with the definition of a category seems to imply that a semigroup homomorphism exists between every possible pair of semigroups. Have I interpreted that correctly? If so, I think that's wrong.
For example, semigroups do not require commutativity. So, consider two semigroups, $A = (S, \circ)$ and $B = (T, \cdot)$, where $A$ is commutative and $B$ is not. Let's attempt to find a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$. That is, a map $f : S \to T$ satisfying
$$
\begin{equation}
  f(a \circ b) = f(a) \cdot f(b),
\end{equation}
$$
for all $a,b \in S$. Since $A$ is commutative, $f(a \circ b) = f(b \circ a)$. However, $B$ is not commutative such that $f(a) \cdot f(b) \neq f(b) \cdot f(a)$ in general. Therefore, there is no homomorphism from $A$ to $B$.
We can also consider the inverse case of a homomorphism from $B$ to $A$. Now, we look for a map $g : T \to S$ satisfying
$$
\begin{equation}
  g(x \cdot y) = g(x) \circ g(y),
\end{equation}
$$
for all $x,y \in T$. $B$ is not commutative so $g(x \cdot y) \neq g(y \cdot x)$ in general. However, $A$ is commutative, so $g(x) \circ g(y) = g(y) \circ g(x)$. Therefore, there is no homomorphism from $B$ to $A$.
Am I correct? If so, is it not possible to define the class of all semigroups as a category where morphisms are defined as semigroup homomorphisms?
Or, perhaps the problem with my logic is explained by the statement "$\mathrm{Mor}(A, B)$ is a set whose elements are morphisms...". That is, the set could be the null set in which case no semigroup homomorphisms exist between the pair of semigroups.

$Mor(A, B)$ could be empty, as you say at the end.

Additionally, let me point out your contradictions do not work. It is very much possible to give examples of a commutative semigroup and a non-commutative semigroup with morphisms in either direction. (And it is also possible to give such examples where no morphisms exists in either direction.)

The set of morphisms only has to contain an element when $A = B$, in which case you do need an identity morphism, but otherwise it can very well be empty.

@Thorgott Ah, ok. If you're willing to provide an example of a pair of commutative and non-commutative semigroups with semigroup homomorphisms in both directions, that would be helpful.

@MattHusz Take any abelian group and any non-abelian group. Groups are examples of semigroups, but between groups there is always the trivial homomorphism. (If you want non-trivial homomorphisms, you can e.g. take $\mathbb{Z}$ and the free group on two generators.)

Answering the question in the comment section is against the site guidelines. See How do comments work for more information.

@MartinBrandenburg that's probably my fault, since I answered my own question at the end of the post and people are simply affirming that. I'm going to vote to close my own question, as it's not very good.

I’m voting to close this question because I answered my own question at the end of the post.
